# Некорректное поведение animation-list на кастомных android прошивках(Пример MIUI 7)

Tags: android, android-animation, android-widgets

Есть картинка png 59х149 80 штук. Создал ресурс для анимации:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loader_horizontal_00000" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loader_horizontal_00001" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loader_horizontal_00002" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loader_horizontal_00003" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loader_horizontal_00004" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loader_horizontal_00005" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loader_horizontal_00006" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loader_horizontal_00007" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loader_horizontal_00008" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loader_horizontal_00009" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loader_horizontal_00010" android:duration="50"/>
....
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loader_horizontal_00079" android:duration="50"/>
</animation-list>
```

И использовал его на ProgressBar(circle) следующим образом:

```
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/anim_loader"
            android:indeterminateOnly="true"

 />
```

На всех устройствах это отображается корректно. Но на самсунгах перестает работать(Не помещается в контейнер, если растянуть на всего родителя то зацикливается - две анимации подряд и.т.п. )
Сталкивался ли кто-то с чем то подобным и какие(хотя бы общие) советы можете дать для борьбы с этим.

UPD
Решил это на samsung поменяв ProgressBar на ImageView. Столкнулся с ошибкой на Redmi Note 2(MIUI 7). Грешу на то что это проблема связанная с кастомными прошивками. Может кто-то уже боролся с этим?